# C# TableAdapter doesn't insert and update

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I have a database called DB.mdf, in my program I use this code to insert a new row in this database:

```
DBDataSet ds = new DBDataSet();
DBDataSetTableAdapters.IPTableAdapter ipadap = new DBDataSetTableAdapters.IPTableAdapter();

ipadap.InsertQuery(ip);
```

InsertQuery is: `INSERT INTO [IP] ([ID], [indirizzo]) VALUES (0, @indirizzo);`

The program executes all steps, but not inserts the row on database. Why?

UPDATE
Now I have tried this code:

```
DBDataset.IPRow newRegionRow;
newRegionRow = db.IP.NewIPRow();
newRegionRow.ID = "6";
newRegionRow.indirizzo = "NorthWestern";
// Add the row to the Region table
this.db.IP.Rows.Add(newRegionRow);
// Save the new row to the database
this.ipadap.Update(this.db.IP);
```

And in this case not write a new row in database

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? INSERT INTO [IP] ([ID], [indirizzo]) VALUES (0, @indirizzo); I see that you pass Id of 6 in your code.

Comment: Yes, the code is correct, I haven't any errors. It loads correctly on Dataset but not loads the data on the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error!!! I didn't know that Visual Studio, during develop, create a copy of database in /bin and it work with the copy of database.

Thanks to all.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx